# Get the internal URLSession errors

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

I'm trying to figure out how to get the `URLSession` errors and how to determine if a URLSession failed. I use this code to make the request, with this method I can retrieve the errors sent by the server but I need the errors printed in the console.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
   guard let data = data else { return }
}

task.resume()
```

Those are the errors I want to show in my app, but I don't know how to get it as a string.
[image]
And most of all I need to determine if the task finished with errors

Comment: What is in the `error` value in this case. (You're not going to get those exact strings, but you should get information about the connection error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can obtain description of the error with `error.localizedDescription`

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
               guard error == nil else {
                 // show the alert here
                return }
                guard let data = data else { return }

    }


task.resume()
```